# Django view with cross-domain Ajax

Tags: ajax, django

I have a Django view that I want to integrate with an Ajax call. The call is happening cross domain. I have this code running by itself and making the request cross-domain.

```
def myview(_request):  
    response = HttpResponse(json.dumps({"key": "value", "key2": "value"}))  
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"  
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, OPTIONS"  
    response["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = "1000"  
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*"  
    return response
```

I am wondering how to integrate this into my existing view. You will see what I have tried in the code below:

```
def american_time(request):
    #Calling the HTML Source from the URL
    sock = urllib.urlopen("http://apps.cbp.gov/bwt/index.asp")
    htmlSource = sock.read()
    sock.close()
    #create a soup object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource)
    #find the tags we need and their content
    bridge = soup.findAll('td', limit=215)[194]
    tunnel = soup.findAll('td', limit=250)[208]
    #new variables to be passed
    contents_of_tunnel = tunnel.getText(', ')
    contents_of_bridge = bridge.getText(', ')
    #check to see if there is a delay for the bridge
    if 'no delay' in contents_of_bridge:
        time_to_cross_the_bridge = 0
    else:
        inside_of_bridge = re.split(r', ', contents_of_bridge)
        number_inside_of_bridge = inside_of_bridge[1]
        list_for_time_to_cross_the_bridge = re.findall(r"\d+", number_inside_of_bridge)
        time_to_cross_the_bridge = list_for_time_to_cross_the_bridge[0]
    if 'no delay' in contents_of_tunnel:
        time_to_cross_the_tunnel = 0
    else:
        inside_of_tunnel = re.split(r', ', contents_of_tunnel)
        number_inside_of_tunnel = inside_of_tunnel[1]
        list_for_time_to_cross_the_tunnel = re.findall(r"\d+", number_inside_of_tunnel)
        time_to_cross_the_tunnel = list_for_time_to_cross_the_tunnel[0]
    response = HttpResponse(json.dumps({"bridge_time": time_to_cross_the_bridge,      "tunnel_time": time_to_cross_the_tunnel}))
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
    response["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = "1000"
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*"
    #finally, return as Ajax
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

AJAX:

```
$.get( "http://localhost:8000/us", function(json){
$('#timeone').html(json.bridge_time + "min delay");
$('#timetwo').html(json.tunnel_time + "min delay");
})
.fail(function(){
    alert('We can\'t get data right now! Please try again later.');
})
.done(function(){
    alert('Success!');
});
```

However, I am still getting the message `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/us. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` in the console. How can I integrate this header into my view?

Comment: What is the code to send ajax?

Comment: Yes. Maybe this help: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings See `crossdomain` option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add this [middleware](https://gist.github.com/barrabinfc/426829).

How to add see documentation  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: Its not working for me. Tried each step and all troubleshooting. any specific point to look?